# How to get the MainWindow winId from a subclass?

Tags: c++, windows, qt

When i have the subclass below running in two different 'MainWindow' guis, how i could get the winId from the 'MainWindow' which this widget belongs to?

I tried:

```cpp
class Test: public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    
    Test(QWidget* parent = 0) : QFrame(parent)
    {
        QWidget* widget = this;
        while (widget->parentWidget() != NULL)
        {
            widget = widget->parentWidget();
            //qDebug() << "name: " << widget->objectName();
        }

        HWND id = (HWND)widget->winId();
    }
}
```

Theres another way than walking over parentWidget()?

Comment: Just walk up the parent chain until `widget->parentWidget()` becomes null. Having null for parent is the definition of the top-level window.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwidget.html#effectiveWinId